# Rendering content in Asp.net MVC 5 twitter bootstrap tabs

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have the below mark up for tabs in twitter **bootstrap**. My question is how do I make the content for the activated tab visible when clicked by the user?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">tab3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4">tab4</a></li>
</ul>

<div>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active">
            page 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane">
            page 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane">
            page 3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab4" class="tab-pane">
            page 4
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With JavaScript: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs